# Load-balancing users over different versions

Tags: load-balancing, versioning

I'm currently dabling into some distributed environments and I got a question about load-balancing between different versions.

I sort of want to achieve a situation where:

- 2 or more versions of a SaaS application
- Multiple clients for the application
- Each client can run on different version but using same DNS name

I was looking at L7 load balancing and maybe some sort of cookie usage, but i'm really inexperienced in this field and was wondering if this is possible or what other solutions there are.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into [JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) as a carrier of relevant session information which can work in combination with cookies and L7 traffic analysis to achieve what you want to do here.

For example you could have the JWT carry the user session claims and information on the server version the user needs to connect to, and then possibly use cookies and session stickiness to aid in faster routing of an existing and valid session to the correct server or server group for the duration of the JWT validity period, or similar.